# Find the Maclaurin series for function $f(x)$ and determine its interval of convergence.

Tags: taylor-expansion

$$f(x) = \frac{3}{1+x-2x^2}$$
I have to evaluate $f^{(8)}(0)$ and find its interval of convergence. The problem is I don't know how to find it since counting derivatives ($f''(x)$, $f'''(x)$, ...) is tedious. Is there any way to do it in faster and more efficient way?

Comment: Have you decomposed the function into 2 partial fractions? One of the fractions you should know the maclaurin series for already.

Comment: I've been thinking about 3 $1\over(1-(2x^2 - x))$

Comment: Bottom side can be factored into $(2x+1)(1-x)$. Then you end up with $\frac{2}{2x+1} + \frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Didnt think about that, thanks!